# Exercise 10, Section 5.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over the field $F$. Prove that there are at most $n$ distinct scalars $x$ in $F$ such that $\text{det}(xI-A)=0$.

**My attempt:** Let $f:F\to F$ defined by $f(x)=\text{det}(xI-A)$, $\forall x\in F$, be a polynomial function. We show $\text{deg}(f)=n$. By theorem 2 section 5.3, $f(x)=\text{det}(xI-A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn}\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^nx\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))$. We claim, $\text{deg}\left(\prod_{i=1}^nx\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))\right)=n$$\iff$$\sigma=\text{id}_{J_n}$. Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$ Assume towards contradiction, $\sigma\neq \text{id}_{J_n}$. Then $\exists j\in J_n$ such that $\sigma(j)\neq j$. Since $\sigma$ is surjective, $\exists k\in J_n$ such that $\sigma(k)=j$. Clearly $k\neq j$. So $\sigma(k)\neq k$. So $\exists j,k\in J_n$ such that $j\neq k$, $\sigma (j)\neq j$ and $\sigma (k)\neq k$. Then
$$\prod_{i=1}^nx\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))= A(j,\sigma (j))A(k,\sigma (k))\prod_{i\in J_n\setminus \{j,k\}}x\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i)).$$
So $\text{deg}\left( \prod_{i\in J_n\setminus \{j,k\}}x\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))\right) \leq n-2\lt n$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $\text{deg}\left(\prod_{i=1}^nx\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))\right)=n$. Hence $\sigma =\text{id}_{J_n}$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely, suppose $\sigma =\text{id}_{J_n}$. Then $\sigma (i)=i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. So $\prod_{i=1}^nx\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))= \prod_{i=1}^nx-A(i,\sigma (i))$. Thus $\text{deg}\left(\prod_{i=1}^nx-A(i,\sigma (i))\right)=n$. This completes the proof of claim.

So $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(x-A(i,\sigma (i))\right) +\sum_{\sigma \in S_n \setminus \{\text{id}_{J_n}\}}(\text{sgn}\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^nx\delta_{i\sigma(i)}-A(i,\sigma (i))$. Hence $\text{deg}(f)=n$. By theorem 4 corollary 2 section 4.4, $\exists$ at most $n$ roots in $F$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Your proof is correct in my opinion. There are other ways. Eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_k$ corresponding to different eigenvalues form a linear subspace of dimension $k.$ Hence $k \le n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for your feedback. Can you please elaborate more on different approach, using eigenvectors and eigenvalues? Because in book that notion is not yet defined.

Comment: A number $r$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if there exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av=rv$ i.e. $(rI-A)v=0.$ The last condition implies that the columns of $rI-A$ are linearly dependent hence $\det(rI-A)=0.$ It can be shown that if $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_k$ are different eigenvalues then the corresponding nonzero vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_k$ are linearly independent. Hence they span a linear subspace of dimension $k$ in the entire space. Hence $k\le n.$ If those notions are ahead in your algebra course, you may ignore that solution.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Your proof is insane! I known $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$$\iff$det$(\lambda I-T)=0$ result. I have seen “if $\lambda_1,…,\lambda_m$ are distinct eigenvalues of $T$ & $v_1,··· ,v_m$ be corresponding eigenvectors, then $v_1 , · · · , v_m$ is independent” result in [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj-3Ia7sOr6AhX7S2wGHZmPDXwQFnoECCsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.ox.ac.uk%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Fattachments%2FLinearAlgebraII.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3WDd8PAAvGFNLok8kQyMRC) lecture notes (pg no.13, theorem 2.11) but haven’t yet proved it by myself.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Following is my proof using your idea: there are at most $n$ distinct scalars $x$ in $F$ such that $\text{det}(xI-A)=0$, is same as saying, there are at most $n$ distinct eigenvalue of $A\in M_n(F)$. Assume towards contradiction, $\exists k\gt n$ eigenvalue of $A$. Let $\lambda_1,…, \lambda_k$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and $v_1,…,v_n$ be corresponding eigenvectors. So $\{v_1,…,v_n\}$ is independent. Since dim$(V)=n$, we have $k= | \{v_1,…,v_n\}|\leq n$. Thus $k\leq n$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $k\gt n$. Hence $\exists k\neq n$ eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I would really appreciate if you write your version of proof in answer. I will gladly accept it.

Comment: There is a typo, it should be $\{v_1,…,v_k\}$, not $\{v_1,…,v_n\}$. And $k\leq n$, not $k\neq n$.

Comment: A proof I have proposed is standard. That's not my original idea. Your proof is good as well and you may see it on page 12 of the notes you have found on the net.