# Exercise 11, Section 5.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$. Show that if $A$ is invertible there are at most $n$ scalars $x$ in $F$ for which the matrix $xA + B$ is not invertible.

**My attempt:** By theorem 4 section 5.4, $xA+B$ is not invertible$\iff$$\det (xA+B)=0$. Since $A$ is invertible, $\exists A^{-1}\in M_n(F)$ such that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I_n$. We claim, $\det (xI+BA^{-1})=0$$\iff$$\det (xA+B)=0$. Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\det (xI+BA^{-1})=0$. Multiply both side by $\det (A)$, we have $\det (xI+BA^{-1})\cdot \det (A)=\det [(xI+BA^{-1})\cdot A]=\det (xA+B)=0$. Thus $\det (xA+B)=0$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely, suppose $\det (xA+B)=0$. Then $(xA+B)\cdot A^{-1}=xI+BA^{-1}$. So $\det [(xA+B)\cdot A^{-1}]=\det (xA+B)\cdot \det (A^{-1})=0=\det (xI+BA^{-1})$. Thus $\det (xI+BA^{-1})=0$. Our desired result. By [exercise 10 section 5.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4555292/861687), $\exists$ at most $n$ scalar $x\in F$ such that $\det (xI+BA^{-1})=0$. Thus $\exists$ at most $n$ scalar $x\in F$ such that $\det (xA+B)=0$. Hence $\exists$ at most $n$ scalar $x\in F$ such that $xA+B$ is not invertible. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Slight variation of above proof: $(xA+B)\cdot A^{-1}=xI+BA^{-1}$. So $\det [(xA+B)\cdot A^{-1}]=\det (xA+B)\cdot \det (A^{-1})=\det (xI+BA^{-1})$. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\det (xI+BA^{-1})=0$. Then $\det (xA+B)\cdot \det (A^{-1})=0$. Since $A$ is invertible, $\det (A^{-1})\neq 0$. So $\det (xA+B)=0$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\det (xA+B)=0$. Then $\det (xA+B)\cdot \det (A^{-1})=\det (xI+BA^{-1})=0$.